# Why is my bootstrap navbar not showing the active button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

[image: what the navbar looks like]

I'm trying to use bootstrap for the first time and I understand I need to link the js and stylesheets in the head, this is in a master page btw. I did that and It's supposed to set the active class to whichever page is clicked on. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, sorry if this has a simple solution I'm not aware of.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Style/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Style/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

https://pastebin.com/nBKYaRzh

this code wouldn't format properly here so I had to post it on pastebin.

Comment: Each button is a new url , this will be when asp generate html content, added the specifica class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar-default menu">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Shittalk.tf</a>
         </div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.menu li').click(function(e) {
   console.log("hello")
   var $this = $(this);

   $("li").removeClass("active")
   $this.addClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
  </script>
```

Don't forget to add Bootstrap and jQuery for this. 
[working example](https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/awQpvG?editors=1010)

Comment: you should have a `<script>.... </script>` somewhere in your template.
somewhere between that script tags (where the dots "..." are). I will edit the Post you can check it out. Maybe you need a ` $(document).ready(function(){` at the beginning

Comment: @dvs the second code would also have to go between the script tags ;)

Comment: ok ty very much but it isn't working still. Do I need any prerequisits for this?What do I need to put in the classforthisnav? do I need to have ids for each list item?

Comment: https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/awQpvG?editors=1010 check it out. Its working. one of your divs should have the class "menu"

Comment: You can copy paste the exact code from codepen. If there is a bug its probably because you don't have jQuery or Bootstrap installed.